# How to print the total number of row count in tables in specific schema?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

i want to calculate the number of row counts in tables present in specific schema.i have calculated the row count of the tables but i want output in format:-

```
Total number of Row Count for table_name is :[value]
```

I have prepared the scripts in which i an getting the count of every table present in the schema. But my concern is i want the output like :-

```
total no. of row count in table_name is [value].
```

something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

databasename="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/.bash_profile |grep PGDATABASE|awk '{print $1}'|cut -d '=' -f2|cut -d ';' -f1)"
echo "$databasename"

listof_table="select t.table_name from information_schema.tables t where t.table_schema = 'emp_history' and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' order by t.table_name;"

listof_schema="select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name ='emp_history';"

query_count="select 'select count(*) from ' || tablename || ' ;' from pg_tables where schemaname='emp_history';"

var2="$(psql -U enterprisedb -d $databasename -c "$listof_schema" -L /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log)"

sed -i -e "1,6d" /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log

final_schema_list="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log| head -1|tr -d "[:blank:]" > /home/enterprisedb/final_list.log)"

count="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/final_list.log)"

echo "$count"

var1="$(psql -U enterprisedb -d $databasename -c "$listof_table" -L /home/enterprisedb/table_name.log)"

sed -i -e "1,6d" -e '$d' /home/enterprisedb/table_name.log

table_name="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/table_name.log |tr -d "[:blank:]" > /home/enterprisedb/table_name_final.log)"

table_name1="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/table_name_final.log )"

final_table_name="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/table_name_final.log|head -n -1 > /home/enterprisedb/final.log)"

table_name_final="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/final.log)"

echo "$table_name_final"
for i in $table_name_final
do
        table_count="$(psql -U enterprisedb -d $databasename -c "select count(*) from "$count"."$i";")"
        echo "Total number of Row Count for "$i" is : "$table_count""

done
```

I want result like:-

```
Total number of Row Count for table_name is :[value]
```

But actually its printing output like:-

```
 count
-------
     2
(1 row)

Total number of Row Count for mail_template is :
 count
-------
     1
(1 row)

Total number of Row Count for mail_template_key is :
 count
-------
     7
(1 row)

Total number of Row Count for v_biel_kategorie is :
 count
-------
    40
(1 row)

Total number of Row Count for v_sample_type is :
```

print the count first then table name.

Comment: Just curious: this is of course doable in bash, but is it really the best tool for that? Python (but also Perl for old-timers, etc.) would offer the list structures and facilities to easily solve that problem. Or else why not writing a stored procedure in postgres, which does the total for you?

Comment: `echo "The number is:" $(psql -c "\pset tuples_only on" -c "select 1")` The key point here is `\pset tuples_only on`

Comment: Thanks for the support it has been resolved . just an quotes error. the above query is working fine and helps to find the tables counts in schema automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach how to use `psql` output in shell scripts.

For single row output:

```
IFS=$'\t' read a b <<< $(psql -X -c "copy (select 1, random()) to stdout with (format csv, delimiter e'\\t')")
echo "a=$a, b=$b"
```

For multi row output:

```
TEMP_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\t'
while read a b; do
    echo "a=$a, b=$b"
done <<< $(psql -X -c "copy (select i, random() from generate_series(1,5) as i) to stdout with (format csv, delimiter e'\\t')")
IFS=$TEMP_IFS
echo "a=$a, b=$b"
```

(Note that the values of `$a` and `$b` variables is not available outside of `while` block)

Here:

- `-X` `psql` option: do not use the `~/.psqlrc` file to avoid unnecessary output
- `copy (<query>) to stdout with (format csv, delimiter e'\\t')`: output the result of `<query>` using `CSV` format with <kbd>Tab</kbd> character as delimiter
- `IFS=$'\t'`: Temporary set the default shell delimiter to <kbd>Tab</kbd> character
   (here is special syntax for string constants, compare `echo "a\tb"; echo -e "a\tb"; echo $'a\tb'`)
- `read a b`: read input delimited by `$IFS` into the variable(s)
- `<<<`: use the followed value as input to the previous command
- ... etc

Comment: above script is correct kindly use for the table count for specific schema