# How to delete the set of range lines and last line using bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash

How to delete the set of few lines from the log files and the last line?

I have the log file which contains the set of lines like:-

Query:

```
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name ='emp_his';
```

```
 schema_name
-------------
 emp_his
(1 row)
```

I want only `emp_his` string rest all lines to be deleted.
I have prepared the scripts head and tail command it's working.  I have pasted both the code but `$d` command not working why?
This code is working:

```
databasename="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/.bash_profile |grep PGDATABASE|awk '{print $1}'|cut -d '=' -f2|cut -d ';' -f1)"
echo "$databasename"


listof_schema="select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name ='emp_his';"


var2="$(psql -U enterprisedb -d $databasename -c "$listof_schema" -L /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log)"

sed -i -e "1,6d" /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log
final_schema_list="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log| head -1|tr -d "[:blank:]" > /home/enterprisedb/final_list.log)"
count="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/final_list.log)"
echo "$count"
```

But below code is not working:

```
databasename="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/.bash_profile |grep PGDATABASE|awk '{print $1}'|cut -d '=' -f2|cut -d ';' -f1)"
echo "$databasename"


listof_schema="select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name ='emp_his';"


var2="$(psql -U enterprisedb -d $databasename -c "$listof_schema" -L /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log)"

sed -i -e "1,6d" /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log
sed -i -e "$d" /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log > /home/enterprisedb/final_list.log

count="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/final_list.log)"
echo "$count"
```

I want this code to be functional one:

```
databasename="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/.bash_profile |grep PGDATABASE|awk '{print $1}'|cut -d '=' -f2|cut -d ';' -f1)"
echo "$databasename"


listof_schema="select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name ='emp_his';"


var2="$(psql -U enterprisedb -d $databasename -c "$listof_schema" -L /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log)"

sed -i -e "1,6d" /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log
sed -i -e '$ d' /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log > /home/enterprisedb/final_list.log

count="$(cat /home/enterprisedb/final_list.log)"
echo "$count"
```

I want only `emp_his` string in the log files rest all should be deleted.
This can be achieved with the head and tail command but this command
`sed -i -e "$d" /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log` is not working in the Bash scripting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the total number of row count in tables in specific schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886259/how-to-print-the-total-number-of-row-count-in-tables-in-specific-schema)

Comment: no both are different ones. in total no. of row count i have to calculate the row count.  and also i have used the head command to tackle last line emission error but i want sed command to be functional .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$d` `sed` is working but doesn't do what you think it does. Because you've given `sed` the `-i` option, it updates the file in place rather than printing to standard out.

Try

```sh
sed -e "1,6d" -e '$d' /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log >/home/enterprisedb/final_list.log
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. i have tried your code still not working.  when i am runing the code"var2="$(psql -U enterprisedb -d $databasename -c "$listof_schema" -L /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log)"" i am getting the below output     :-      
 ********* QUERY **********
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name ='emp_his';
**************************

 schema_name
-------------
 emp_his
(1 row)

Comment: but when i run "sed -e "1,6d" -e '$d' /home/enterprisedb/schema_name.log >/home/enterprisedb/final_list.log" output is :-  emp_his
(1 row) but i want only emp_his not(1 row)